# Create a model for the names of the properties of a json Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, schema, jsonschema

I download a json file and want to import it to mongodb, but before importing it to the database, i want to write a code in node.js to restructure the json objects and add some additional information to each object.
The structure of each object looks like as following:

```js
{
  "fid": "52955",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        -76.9812226935329,
        38.9032437788008
      ],
      [
        -76.9811595039813,
        38.9033432081856
      ]
    ]
  },
  "signs": [
    {
      "MANUAL_SEGID": null,
      "OBJECTID": "125463",
      "GLOBALID": "{0F7DB59B-948D-42DB-90EF-3F17D391B8BB}",
      "SIGNARROWDIRECTION": "2",
      "MUTCD": "R-DC-Loading_Zone_With_ParkMobile_Zone",
      "intervalInfo": [
        {
          "RESTRICTIONSTATUS": "3",
          "OBJECTID": "41460"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "MANUAL_SEGID": null,
      "OBJECTID": "125465",
      "GLOBALID": "{079902E8-D9B0-462B-9323-1550B4FE7197}",
      "SIGNARROWDIRECTION": "2",
      "MUTCD": "R-DC-2HR",
      "intervalInfo": [
        {
          "RESTRICTIONSTATUS": "1",
          "OBJECTID": "41462"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My aim for creating a model or schema for the json properties is if later some of the NAMES are changed , i could easily apply the changes in the model directly NOT in my javascript code.
Would be great if someone give me a hint.
thanks

A part of my code:

```js
const filesArray = [ "permitZone.geojson"]; //Array of files in manual folder
const dataInfo = {
    description: 'Zone',
    data: [
        {
            url: 'https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/fcfbf29074e549d8aff9b9c708179291_1.geojson',
            type: 'permitZone.geojson'
        }
    ]
};
function dataReader() {
    var allResult = [];

    var arrayFilePromises = filesArray.map(function (fileName, index) {
        return downloadFile(dataInfo.data[index].url, dataDownloadPath, fileName)
            .then((fileRes) => {
                fileRes.features.forEach(function (val) {
                   
                    // Here i need to read each object and apply some changes

                });
            })
    })

    return Promise.all([Promise.all(arrayFilePromises)])
        .then(() => {
            return allResult
        })

}
```

hey, I could write a objectModel.js with the following classes, but i am still confused how can I use a constructor function for an array. in my example this.signs? because val.signs is an array of sign.

```js
class Sign {
    constructor(signData) {
        this.objectId = signData.OBJECTID;
        this.global = signData.GLOBALID;
        this.manualSegId = signData.MANUAL_SEGID;
        this.signarrowDirection = signData.SIGNARROWDIRECTION;
    }
}
class MyCity {
    constructor(val) {
        this.fid = val.fid;
        this.lineId = val.lineId;
        this.segId = val.segId;
        this.geometry = val.geometry;
        this.signs = new Sign(val.signs);
    }

}


module.exports = {
    MyCity: MyCity
}
```

Comment: where is you javascript code

Comment: @AkhilAravind I have a huge code and can not post it here. But I send the parts which i want to fix it

Comment: you can access and modify object with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: @AkhilAravind Class has been implemented  in javascript to make working with objects creation easier and it also cleaner. besides if i want to use some methods , it is easier to define them in class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve it finally, The iteration through the signs array should look like this:

```js
class Sign {
    constructor(signData) {
        this.objectId = signData.OBJECTID;
        this.global = signData.GLOBALID;
        this.manualSegId = signData.MANUAL_SEGID;
        this.signarrowDirection = signData.SIGNARROWDIRECTION;
    }
}

class MyCity {
    constructor(val) {
        this.fid = val.fid;
        this.lineId = val.lineId;
        this.segId = val.segId;
        this.geometry = val.geometry;
        this.signs = val.signs.map(signData => new Sign(signData))
    }

}


module.exports = {
    MyCity: MyCity
}
```